# Flash & graphic-card problems: 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, flash, unknown-device

I'm a new ubuntu user and installed 13.04 on a computer that used to run on xp. Since I installed Ubuntu I had some troubles: 
Unity is not launching: so i use the gnome interface
The flashplayer-plugin was installed but it isn't working on chromium or Firefox. I got this image (it might not show: the website tells me I need 10 reputation): this is the image url: https://01.org/sites/default/files/users/u5193/capture_du_2013-07-23_112436.png

My graphic card wasn't recognised in Configuration>details so I tried these:

- I tried using the mesa-utils
- I tought it might be the driver. I updated the drivers with the
  linux graphic installer.

**BUT** didn't get any change:

- Flash still glitching
- Graphic card/controller remains unknown

The graphic card is a 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller
The current settings are:

- **bits**: 32 bits
- **clock**: 33MHz
- **fonctionnalités**: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
- **configuration**: driver=i915 latency=0
- **ressources**: irq:16 mémoire:f0000000-f7ffffff mémoire:ff280000-ff2fffff portE/S:ec00(taille=8)

Answer (score 2):

For the graphics card to be recognized in Configuration → Details, execute the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

As for the flash-player problem it's a little bit difficult to get any help. Flash player is not an Ubuntu's project, is Adobe's project and currently Adobe dropped flash player support for Linux.

I would suggest two things.

The first called minitube.

```
sudo apt-get install minitube
```

The second called google-chrome.

Download and install it from [Google's site.](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/)